# Gzip Compression and .htaccess file on Bitnami MEAN Stack

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-ec2, gzip, mean-stack, bitnami

I need to add the **gzip compression** to my web-app deployed on *AWS EC2* using *Bitnami Mean Stack*.

To add the gzip compression usually one should configure .htaccess file but, reading the Bitnami Apache Doc, Bitnami seems to deny the use of this file for security reasons. You can see that [here inside the doc](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/apache/#how-to-configure-htaccess-files).

What is the procedure I should follow to add the gzip compression?

Answer (score 0):

You can add gzip compression using the **mod_deflate** Apache module. As you are using a Bitnami Stack, this module is already installed and enabled.
You can add your custom configuration in the following file:

```
 /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/deflate.conf
```

Here you can use the usual Apache directives.

If you perform any change, don't forget to restart the Apache service by executing:

```
 sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```